# Push into array overrides previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to build an array having this format:

```
x = [
      {'projectName': 'a', 'serialNo': 1},
      {'projectName': 'b', 'serialNo': 2},
      {'projectName': 'c', 'serialNo': 3},
]
```

using values passed from a form

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    let x = []
    x.push({
      projectName: form.value.projectName,
      serialNo: form.value.serialNo,
    })

    console.log(x) // -> this will always give me the value I just inserted

    // form.value.project = JSON.stringify(x)
    // putObj(form.value).subscribe((res) => { });
}
```

Then I send form.value in backend and the field `project` is modified. My problem is that everytime I push values into `x`, the previous value overrides.

Which seems to be the problem? If my code is unclear, I can explain or give more snippets.

EDIT: thank you very much! It worked, I declared `x` inside component.

Comment: you allways re-initialize x as an new array

Comment: `x` is declared inside the onSubmit function.

Comment: declare `x` in your component and use `this.x.push` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested, but should work in theory:

```
// ...
private x: {'projectName': string, 'serialNo':number}[] = [];
// ...
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.x.push({
      projectName: form.value.projectName,
      serialNo: form.value.serialNo,
    });

    console.log(this.x)
}
// ...
```

Comment: Just `private x: any = []` was enough. Since you were the first who answered me inside comments section, I will accept your answer.

Comment: sorry :), yes this works too, i allways define the type of the objects in my arrays

Answer (score 3):

```
let x = [] //declare outside

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

    x.push({
      projectName: form.value.projectName,
      serialNo: form.value.serialNo,
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, move your let x = [] outside of function. Not sure what you are planning to do, it might need to be a global variable. Every time you enter the function you set x to be an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

remove the

```
let x = []
```

you can define your array with initial elements within ur onInit method in your component, such as:

```
type x = Array<{projectName: string, serialNo: number}>;

ngOnInit() { 
    this.x = [
        {'projectName': 'a', 'serialNo': 1},
        {'projectName': 'b', 'serialNo': 2},
        {'projectName': 'c', 'serialNo': 3}, 
    ]
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.x.push({
        projectName: form.value.projectName,
        serialNo: form.value.serialNo,
    })
}
```